# lookup konnek-db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host POSTGRES DOCKER WSL2 not connected error

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, wsl-2

i'm relatively new to windows development enviroment used to use ubuntu  before and decided to use windows to try to get best of both world game and development, after follow and research i'm able to setup wsl2, docker and golang since it is my default development needs,

but when i run my docker everything was fine except for the moment where i found that postgres were not connected like this in my docker logs

```
[00] 2020/10/03 10:42:08 host=konnek-db port=5432 user=postgres dbname=konnek password=postgres sslmode=disable
[00] 2020/10/03 10:42:09 dial tcp: lookup konnek-db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[00] panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[00] [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xa0400e]
```

again in my other machine where i used to work were using ubuntu and it runs perfectly without any issue the docker yaml that i'm using were also basicly the same that i used to run in my other machine

i also test this using my datagrip and it also shown the same error
[image]

Comment: In the first error message you're trying to use hostname 'konnek-db' but your DNS server running on 127.0.0.11 does not know that name. Is that the correct hostname? How is your internal DNS supposed to be set up here? Do you know where your postgresql server is actually hosted? Is it in a container, and what local IP address is that container's port forwarded to?

Comment: In the datagrip screenshot, you're trying to use localhost for the database instead of konnek-db. Maybe you can't use konnek-db if your Windows DNS isn't set up to use the docker-hosted 127.0.0.11. So this needs to be the correct IP address for konnek-db from the docker containers as above, or you could e.g. add konnek-db to Windows's hosts file with the correct IP address so that it can resolve it anyway.

Comment: hei @Rup yes my postgresql hosted in the container it host to 0.0.0.0, should i insert this to windows host file? to try to connect?

Comment: No, that's not the address: 0.0.0.0 means 'bind to all available IP addresses in this host / container'. So there will be a different IP address for the container, and the port will probably be forwarded out of the container for non-docker resources to access too in your docker-compose config, or the docker container config. So you'll need to find that to find the correct address to use.

Comment: hey @Rup i'm trying to figure my ip use for the container and find out this 172.18.0.5
with using 

docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end
}}' test-service
do you have any advice how to find the correct address to use?

Comment: Run `docker ps`: in the PORTS column your postgresql container might have a line like `127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp` - that's the IP address you want. That one might also be 0.0.0.0, in which case localhost ought to have worked in datagrip.

Comment: thanks for the advice @Rup after comparing the docker ps port in my pc and in my other machine that running well with docker i find out that postgres 10.11 is not on the list of running container in my pc should i change the config or version of the postgres? or is it because of i'm installing postgresql in my local computer yet? . FYI: i alredy use postgres image 10.11 in my docker yaml

Comment: I don't know about the postgresql docker containers, sorry. The [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) says the latest 10.x is 10.14, so you could try that or just 10, or a later version.

Comment: hey i tried the 10.14 and 10.11 as my default @Rup but dont know why, its still not connected when i try the latest 10.11 and try to docker ps at the postgresql it only shown me the port 5432 without the host 0.0.0.0 and still when i check the lock it return not connected dial tcp: lookup konnek-db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host